# Python drawing a hypotrochoid error?

Tags: python, graphics, draw

Hey guys I have a problem with the draw function of my Python project. I am required to draw a hypotrochoid with an input of a list of points generated by a different function. My draw function

```
def draw(points):
     win = GraphWin("My Hypotrochoid", 1000, 1000)
     hypo = Polygon(points)
     hypo.draw(win)
     win.getMouse() # Pause to view result
     win.close()    # Close window when done
```

with the parameter "points" being a list of x and y coordinates to be drawn. The error i'm getting:

```
  File "//uniwa.uwa.edu.au/userhome/students8/21133788/Desktop/CITS1401/2015/Project 1/ok/project1.py", line 75, in draw
    hypo = Polygon(points)
  File "//uniwa.uwa.edu.au/userhome/students8/21133788/Desktop/CITS1401/2015/Project 1/ok\graphics.py", line 643, in __init__
    self.points = list(map(Point.clone, points))
  File "//uniwa.uwa.edu.au/userhome/students8/21133788/Desktop/CITS1401/2015/Project 1/ok\graphics.py", line 531, in clone
    other = Point(self.x,self.y)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I get this error after using the array of x and y coordinates generated by another function from my project as the "points" parameter, I suspect that the Polygon method doesn't recognise arrays as inputs... I could be wrong though.

The module i'm using for this project is John Zelle's graphics.py module, http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/graphics.html, as we are not allowed to use turtle graphics for this project.

Please let me know what I've done wrong, and thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick terminology nitpick: "array" is not a built-in Python type. Unless you imported the [`array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module, you're almost certainly not using arrays.

```
hypo = Polygon(points)
```

You appear to be sending a tuple of points to the Polygon initializer here. However, the documentation says:

> Polygon(point1, point2, point3, ...)
>       Constructs a polygon having the given points as vertices. Also accepts a single parameter that is a **list** of the vertices.

Looks like it only accepts lists, not tuples. Investigating the source code confirms this.

```
class Polygon(GraphicsObject):

    def __init__(self, *points):
        # if points passed as a list, extract it
        if len(points) == 1 and type(points[0]) == type([]):
            points = points[0]
```

`type(points[0]) == type([])` will certainly not work if `points[0]` is a tuple.

Luckily, the fix is straightforward.

```
hypo = Polygon(list(points))
```

Alternatively, just create `points` as a list in the first place. If you have code that looks like `points = (whatever, whatever, whatever)`, change it to `points = [whatever, whatever, whatever]`.

Alternatively again, use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) so the `Polygon` initializer sees your arguments as separate items, rather than one tuple.

```
hypo = Polygon(*points)
```